# How do I build a nested form in Refinerycms?

Tags: refinerycms

I am trying to nest a form with two resources (Map and Location).
I'm following the Nested Forms tutorial from Ryan Bates however I must be missing something.

Map Model:

```
module Refinery
  module Maps
    class Map < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      self.table_name = 'refinery_maps'

      attr_accessible :name, :position, :questions_attributes

      validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
      has_many :locations

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations 
    end
  end
end
```

Location Model:

```
module Refinery
  module Maps
    class Location < Refinery::Core::BaseModel

      attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :address, :description, :title, :position

      validates :address, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
      belongs_to :map
    end
  end
end
```

View:

Controller(decorator):

```
Refinery::PagesController.class_eval do

  before_filter :new

  private  
    def new
      @map = Map.new
      3.times { @map.locations.build }
    end

  end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "refinery_maps_locations", :force => true do |t|
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.integer  "map_id"
  end

  create_table "refinery_maps", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

Routes:

```
Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.draw do

  # Frontend routes
  namespace :maps do
    resources :maps, :path => '', :only => [:index, :show]
  end

  # Admin routes
  namespace :maps, :path => '' do
    namespace :admin, :path => Refinery::Core.backend_route do
      resources :maps, :except => :show do
        collection do
          post :update_positions
        end
      end
    end
  end


  # Frontend routes
  namespace :maps do
    resources :locations, :only => [:index, :show]
  end

  # Admin routes
  namespace :maps, :path => '' do
    namespace :admin, :path => "#{Refinery::Core.backend_route}/maps" do
      resources :locations, :except => :show do
        collection do
          post :update_positions
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `:locations_attributes` in your Map model - you have `:questions_attributes` there instead.

Also, check out this gem for refinerycms nested models - https://github.com/llamadigital/refinerycms-nested_models

Just replace "nested_models" with the name of the one you want to nest. It works much better with refinery than nested forms.